# Authentication with WAAD

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I searched for an answer for several days. I would like to handle the management of users of my application with Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD). All code examples that I find necessarily involves having authentication via a web page to sign. Exist there a solution to authenticate without having to use a webpage but spend a login / password ?

Comment: can you elaborate and edit your question ?! what do you mean by "spend a long / password" ? And about what web page are you talking about ?! What application do you target (web, desktop, mobile Xamarin, mobile Native,etc.) what plarform ...

Comment: You need to search for "passive" authentication utilising WS Federation.

Answer (score 1):

tdelepine, Azure AD only supports interactive web SSO based sign-in for Web Applications: OpenIDConnect/SAML/WSFed or OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow.

However, if you're writing a mobile app (rich-client/public client) - Azure AD supports non-interactive auth too, where your app receives username and password from the user and authenticates the user with Azure AD. Do note that the disadvantage of non-interactive auth is that it fails when multi-factor auth is turned on for the user (more and more customers of Azure AD are turning on MFA). 
If you must use the non-interactive auth flow, here' the steps:

- For users that authenticate in the cloud (password is in Azure AD): mobile app uses the resource owner password credential grant OAuth flow (sends the username password of the user to the token endpoint and gets back access token/refresh token)
- For users that authenticate at their on-premises or federated STSs like ADFS, PingFederate, OneLogin etc. (password is not in Azure AD): mobile app discovers the active auth endpoint of the federated STS using GetUserRealm call, authenticates the user at the federated STS using username password using WS-Trust and gets a SAML token, and uses the extensions grant OAuth flow (sends the SAML token to the token endpoint and gets back access token/refresh token)

ADAL.net does all of that for that for you. See the headless auth sample here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet

You can trace the calls in fiddler to reverse engineer for another technology.

Hope that helps.